# Get chrome/brave browser to use png version of favicon

Tags: html, favicon

**Unsolved**

**I want the proper png to show up in the browser tab while still maintain the app I use to connect my website with uses the gif favicon**

So I'm using metamask as an extension and it automatically looks for the first favicon so thus my first favicon is a gif for an animation. But while firefox automatically uses the png version of my favicon, how do I get a browser like Chrome to use the png version as well in the browser tab menu?

So the HTML goes like this...

```
<link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/animation.gif" type="image/gif" >
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon144.png" />
```

The first is the gif which I need to be first due to metamask and the second is the png version which chrome skips over.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using Chrome version 79.0.3945.117. Using this code in HTML, it correctly displays the PNG icon.

Code:

```
<link rel="icon" href="animation.gif" type="image/gif" >
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png">
```

There doesn't seem to be any problems or interferences with my case.

For debugging, I recommend that you check for any 404 errors finding the image, or in other words, the wrong `href` route. Also, try clearing the cache of your browser and reload.

Glad to answer.